# The ifconfig command is not running

Tags: ifconfig

I am using Kali Linux through `vmware` . I tried to use `ifconfig` command. but it shows error message `command doest exist`.
please give me a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

some times in other linux distros when I ran into ifconfig without sudo I got the same message.

my suggestion is run it as sudo ifconfig.

if still exists let me know about other terminal commands working.